# Angular js controller design passing data of http post response to another controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I am new to Angularjs. I have a question on the design of controllers and sharing of data.

I have the first partial `upload.html` which uses `UploadCntrl` for uploading a word document to the server using `$http.post`. Server calls are encapsulated in `uploadService`. On the server side I anlayse the frequency of appearances of a list of words in the document and return that information as response to the `$http.post`.

Back in the `UploadCntrl`, on success I want to direct/show the second partial report.html which uses `AnalyseCntrl` to show the response of the analysis (`$http.post` mentioned above) in a tabular form.

How can I share the analysis reponse in `UploadCntrl` with `AnalyseCntrl`?

Is this the right approach for designing the controllers?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to create a service and inject it into both controllers.

```
app.service("sharedService", function () {
    return {
        sharedObject: {data: null}
    };
});
```

Now in each controller, something like this:

```
app.controller("myController", ["$scope", "$http", "$filter", "storageService",   function($scope, $http, $filter, storageService) {

    // We don't need to put it on the $scope but it makes it available to the view
    $scope.shared = storageService.sharedObject;
    ...
    // After the following line, the other controller will have access to 
    // storageService.sharedObject.myThing as well. Easy!
    $scope.shared.myThing = "your thing";
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing data in AngularJS is best done via [services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) or [factories](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers). Another option would be to store the response inside the `local storage` of the browser, and then access it inside the `AnalyseCntrl`.

So, something like that inside the `UploadCntrl`:

```
anaylseAPI.sendToAnalyse(object).then( function (response) {
 localStorage.setItem("howMany", response.amount);
});
```

And then accessing the `localStorage` inside the `AnaylseCntrl`.

**Another solution is using services.**

They behave like Singletons, so you can use them as data stores.

```
angular
  .module( 'app', [])
  .service('DataStore', DataStore);

function DataStore() {

  this.amount = 0;

  return function(amountOf) {
    this.amount = amountOf;
  };
}
```

Now `inject` the Service in both controllers, and save/get the data from it.

Comment: Appreciate all the answers. Thanks.

Comment: Services are singletons so will it cause any issue when services are shared with multiple controllers to store the response of a post request in the case of multiple requests/multi user/ multi browser scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

You can write an angularjs service that is responsible for sending your post request. In this service you can have a variable store your response and provide a getter-method to retrieve the value of this variable.

Additionally, you may want to provide a function that takes your file as a parameter and make your `$http` request. As soon as you get your response of your server, you assign the response value to your variable and send a broadcast.

The broadcast can be something like this

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('response-recieved');
```

What you then have to do is to inject this service in both of your controllers, listen to the broadcast event and then call the get-method of your service to retrieve the response.

You can do this like this:

```
$scope.$on('response-recieved', function() {
    var myResponse = MyService.getResponse();
}
```

[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_services.htm) you can find an example of how to use a service. Let me know if this helps you.